# How to manually include PSpell into php project

Tags: php, aspell, pspell

The documentation on PSpell mentions command line: http://php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php

Other questions/answers mention command line as well.

Is there a way to simply enable it in php 5.4 maybe in the php.ini file, or a way to download files and manually include them in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSSpell is PHP binary extension. You cannot include it into your project - you need to tell PHP about it and the proper way is to use `php.ini`. If you got no access (i.e. shared hosting etc) then you are out of luck - contact server admin in such case.

Some time ago PHP offered ability to include binary modules directly from PHP scripts (with help of `dl()` function) but for security reasons `dl()` is gone since PHP 5.3

Answer (score 2):

PSSpell is a **PHP module**, so your hosting admin should configure PHP adding this module. There is no way to add it modifying the php.ini.

You can see the active modules with the **php_info()** function or (if you have shell access) with **php -m**.